# group by and count unique entries with more than one entry in time period

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas df as follows:

```
Date            UserID
2022-01-01       ABC
2022-01-02       ABC
2022-01-03       ABC
2022-01-01       DEF
2022-01-05       DEF 
2022-01-10       GHI
```

I want to group by `year` and `month` and count the number of `unique` userID's that appear more than one time.
So my result would look like:

```
YEAR   MONTH   COUNT
2022    1       2
```

Please do note, that since `ABC` and `DEF` occurred more than once, they were counted, but since ````GHI``` didn't occur more than once, it was not counted.
I tried

```
df.group_by(['YR','MONTH'].agg({'USERID':'count'})
```

But this just does a count and `nunique` counts entries that appear once as well.

I want to count entries that appear more than once only.

Comment: So you want to count unique IDs that appeared more than once in a particular year-month? Or are you interested in the number of unique IDs that appeared more than once in the whole year?

Answer (score 1):

Generate year and month columns :

```py
temp =  df.assign(YEAR = df.Date.dt.year, MONTH = df.Date.dt.month)
```

Filter for only duplicated values:

```py
temp = temp.loc[temp.duplicated(subset = ['YEAR', "MONTH", 'UserID'])]
```

Groupby by year and month to get unique count:

```py
(temp
.groupby(['YEAR','MONTH'], as_index = False)
.agg(COUNT=('UserID', 'nunique'))
)

   YEAR  MONTH  COUNT
0  2022      1      2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
s = df.groupby(['Year','Month'])['UserID'].value_counts().gt(1)
s = s.loc[s].groupby(['Year','Month']).value_counts()
s.name = 'COUNT'
result = pd.DataFrame(s).reset_index(level=2,drop=True).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    Year    Month   COUNT
0   2022    1       2
```